# Spring Cloud Contract Verifier - Body matching

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-contract

I'm using Spring Cloud Contract Verifier

org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-contract-verifier:jar:2.0.0.M8
org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-contract-maven-plugin:1.2.4.RELEASE

And I have the following contract:

```
request:
  method: GET
  url: /cars/list
response:
  status: 200
  headers:
    Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
  body:
    cars:
      [
        {
          "make": "Ford",
          "model": "Fiesta",
          "year": 2016,
          "price": 16500.50
        },
        {
          "make": "BMW",
          "model": "X1",
          "year": 2014,
          "price": 22000.00
        },
        {
          "make": "NISSAN",
          "model": "Juke",
          "year": 2017,
          "price": 19300.00
        }
      ]
```

Which is then converted in following java code:

```
DocumentContext parsedJson = JsonPath.parse(response.getBody().asString());
assertThatJson(parsedJson).array("['cars']").contains("['model']").isEqualTo("Juke");
assertThatJson(parsedJson).array("['cars']").contains("['make']").isEqualTo("Ford");
assertThatJson(parsedJson).array("['cars']").contains("['year']").isEqualTo(2014);
assertThatJson(parsedJson).array("['cars']").contains("['year']").isEqualTo(2016);
assertThatJson(parsedJson).array("['cars']").contains("['model']").isEqualTo("Fiesta");
assertThatJson(parsedJson).array("['cars']").contains("['make']").isEqualTo("BMW");
assertThatJson(parsedJson).array("['cars']").contains("['year']").isEqualTo(2017);
assertThatJson(parsedJson).array("['cars']").contains("['make']").isEqualTo("NISSAN");
assertThatJson(parsedJson).array("['cars']").contains("['price']").isEqualTo(16500.5);
assertThatJson(parsedJson).array("['cars']").contains("['model']").isEqualTo("X1");
assertThatJson(parsedJson).array("['cars']").contains("['price']").isEqualTo(22000.0);
assertThatJson(parsedJson).array("['cars']").contains("['price']").isEqualTo(19300.0);
```

I have a few issues with this test:

1) It does not take order into account, meaning the following body would still be considered valid:

```
{
  "cars": [
    {
      "make": "NISSAN",
      "model": "Juke",
      "year": 2017,
      "price": 19300.00
    },
    {
      "make": "BMW",
      "model": "X1",
      "year": 2014,
      "price": 22000.00
    },
    {
      "make": "Ford",
      "model": "Fiesta",
      "year": 2016,
      "price": 16500.50
    }
  ]
}
```

2) It just verifies that certain property is present anywhere in the response, meaning the following body would still be considered valid:

```
{
  "cars": [
    {
      "make": "Ford",
      "model": "Juke",
      "year": 2016,
      "price": 19300.00
    },
    {
      "make": "BMW",
      "model": "X1",
      "year": 2017,
      "price": 22000.00
    },
    {
      "make": "NISSAN",
      "model": "Fiesta",
      "year": 2014,
      "price": 16500.50
    }
  ]
}
```

3) It ignores any extra values present in the response, meaning the following body would still be considered valid:

```
{
  "cars": [
    {
      "make": "Ford",
      "model": "Fiesta",
      "year": 2017,
      "price": 22000.00,
      "state": "good"
    },
    {
      "make": "NISSAN",
      "model": "Juke",
      "year": 2016,
      "price": 19300.00,
      "state": "ok"
    },
    {
      "make": "BMW",
      "model": "X1",
      "year": 2014,
      "price": 16500.50
    },
    {
      "make": "Volkswagen",
      "model": "Golf",
      "year": 2018,
      "price": 12500.00,
      "state": "new"
    }
  ]
}
```

I would like the generated test to be more strict and fail on any differences outlined in cases above.

Can it be achieved with Spring Cloud Contract Verifier?

Answer (score 5):

To begin with you have a mismatch of versions

`org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-contract-verifier:jar:2.0.0.M8 org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-contract-maven-plugin:1.2.4.RELEASE`

You are using a plugin in version different than the verifier. Those should match.

Now for your questions

> 1) It does not take order into account, meaning the following body would still be considered valid:

Yes, we don't test it out of the box. You can do it manually by providing your own JSON path matchers for the whole body (https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-contract/single/spring-cloud-contract.html#contract-matchers)

> 2) It just verifies that certain property is present anywhere in the response, meaning the following body would still be considered valid:

Yeah, we assert that the structure is ok, that's the idea of contract tests. If you want more precise verifiactions use the matchers section (https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-contract/single/spring-cloud-contract.html#contract-matchers)

> 3) It ignores any extra values present in the response, meaning the following body would still be considered valid:

And that's absolutely what you should be doing. Ignore unknown fields. You can read more about Postel's law here (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustness_principle)

> I would like the generated test to be more strict and fail on any differences outlined in cases above.

I think you're looking for a schema not a contract test or definition. You can use the Spring Rest Docs integration (https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-contract/single/spring-cloud-contract.html#_generating_stubs_using_rest_docs) and over there enforce how exactly the stub must look like. But IMO (of course I don't know your domain) you're too restrictive.